# Mean subtraction and addition purpose

Tags: matrix, linear-algebra

I read [Efficient and Accurate Approximations of Nonlinear Convolutional Networks](http://www.cv-foundation.org/openaccess/content_cvpr_2015/papers/Zhang_Efficient_and_Accurate_2015_CVPR_paper.pdf) paper. I have this point I don't understand in section 2.1. But may be, my question will be more general.

it is known that **y** $\in R^d$

if **y** is on a low-rank subspace, we can write

$y = M(y-\bar{y}) + \bar{y}$

where M is a d-by-d matrix of a rank d' $<$ d and $\bar{y}$ is the mean vector of response.

My main question is what is the purpose of adding and subtracting the mean vector of y ($\bar{y}$) ? This is just my stupid mathematical calculation,

if
$y = M(y-\bar{y}) + \bar{y}$

so

$(y - \bar{y}) = M(y-\bar{y})$

then, **M** is identity matrix?

So what is the point of adding and subtracting the mean? Also, what it means that M has rank lower than d? Why is the M has rank lower matrix? How to find the M properly? And how to calculate the $\bar{y}$?

Thank you. Please tell me if I better to give more details about this.

Comment: The relation does not imply that $M$ is an identity matrix.  It may be, for example, that $M$ is a projection matrix, and $y - \bar y$ is in the range of $M$.